# How to sum the following list?

Tags: python, list

I have a list like this:

```
a = ['1 MB', '2 MB']
```

I want to sum all the elements in a.

I figured I first have to create integer list and use sum() function. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the built-in `split` to separate the number from the rest of the string

```
>>> a = ['1 MB', '2 MB']
>>> sum([int(s.split(' ')[0]) for s in a])
3
```

`s.split(' ')` creates the list `['1', 'MB']`

Or use a generator expression to avoid the unneeded list that the list comprehension creates:

```
>>> a = ['1 MB', '2 MB']
>>> sum(int(s.split(' ')[0]) for s in a)
3
```

Comment: You can replace the list comprehension with a generator - saves time and memory, especially for big lists.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all of the elements end in `' MB'`, you can do this:

```
sum(map(int, (x[:-3] for x in a)))
```

Breakdown:

- `(x[:-3] for x in a)` takes all but the last three characters of the string.
- `map(int, iterable)` 'maps' the `int` function to each element of the iterable.
- `sum(iterable)` simply sums the elements of the iterable.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `regex` here:

```
In [19]: a = ['1 MB', '2 MB']

In [20]: sum(int(re.search(r'\d+',x).group()) for x in a)
Out[20]: 3
```

where `re.search(r'\d+')` returns something like:

```
In [23]: [re.search(r'\d+',x).group() for x in a]
Out[23]: ['1', '2']
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work for differing multipliers:

```
import re
pattern = "(\d+)\s*(\w+)?"

a = ['1 MB', '2 MB', '3 K', '250' ]

multiplier = { None: 1, 'MB' : 1000000, 'K' : 1000 }

def multi(m):
    if m:
        return int(m.group(1)) * multiplier[m.group(2)]
    else:
        return 0

r = map(multi, [ re.search(pattern, x) for x in a])
print r

print sum(r)
```

With the following output:

```
[1000000, 2000000, 3000, 250]
3003250
```